# How to best partition data in Spark for optimal processing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using a 40 node EMR cluster with 16cores in each node with 1TB memory, the data that I am processing is close to 70GB-80GB.

I am re-partitioning the input Dataframe  so that each executor can process an equal chunk of data, however the re-partitioning is not happening properly and 90% of the heavy lifting is done by 1-2 executors and rest of the executors are enjoying with only MB's of data 
Even if I don't explicitly use repartitions and allow spark to do it, the skewness in partitions still exists

What change should I bring in my spark code so that each executors gets almost equal amount of data for processing and the skewness can be reduced.

Comment: rdd, df, query, join? pls be more explicit

Comment: @thebluephantom, its when the DF is read , the distribution of data across each executors is not happening equally.

Comment: So may be an idea to improve the question.

Comment: what is min size (in MB) of file(s)? Also, share YARN or SPARK executor metrics